# attr is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

attr is not working in IE below is the code:

```
items.each(function( index ) {
        item = $(this);
        itemPrice = parseInt(item.attr("priceforsorting"));

    })
```

It is throwing error"Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'".

Comment: use [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) framework: `item[0].getAttribute('priceforsorting')`

Comment: What versions of IE and jQuery are you using? Do you get that error in other browsers? Have you tried `.prop()` instead?

Comment: Are you sure, that its just `priceforsorting` and not `data-priceforsorting`? because as of my knowledge, there is `priceforsorting` attribute.

Comment: what is item here and i dont think there is any attribute as priceforsorting

Comment: yes it is working fine on chrome and mozilla...yes i am sure it is "priceforsorting" with values.

Comment: I am getting different values for "priceforsorting" for different rowa and on the bases of values, i am sorting the rows

Comment: I tried "item[0].getAttribute('priceforsorting')", it is working on chrome and mozilla but not in IE.

Comment: Could be a case of an incompatible version of IE. What version of IE are you using?